# Exporting and Importing javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, import, export

I think I am asking a simple question but I only started learning javascript in recent days. I was trying to import the exported object present in another file, but not able to access its keys.
In the first file, my code is :

```
module.exports =()=>{
return{
    userid:"userid",
    password:"password"
}};
```

the file name in which it is stored is "demousable.js"

And for importing this object into another file, I wrote the following code in another file

```
const details =require("./demousable");
console.log(details.userid);
```

But I got "undefined" in output.
Please mention where I went wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting a `function` that returns an `object`, if you just want the `object` you have two options.

**Simply export an object:**

```js
module.exports = {
    userid: "userid",
    password: "password"
};
```

##### OR

**Call the function, then access the properties of the returned object:**

```js
const details = require("./demousable");

console.log(details().userid); // <-- Added a pair of brackets
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for asking the noobie question.But appreciated the reply.